# How does the English version of Sailor Moon differ from the original?

Tags: sailor-moon

I know that some changes were made to Sailor Moon when it was translated into English, like that Sailor Uranus and Sailor Neptune are changed from lovers to cousins. What other changes were made?

I'm not asking about name changes, only plot and character changes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Besides the points you made yourself... I do not believe "some" is a word I would use. I actually watched Sailor Moon with Dutch dubs (based on the English version so I got double the misery) and saw the Japanese version after that and got so confused about it. The Japanese and the English version have the same name but that is about the only thing these two have in common. So no, to me "some" does not even come close.

Each episode was different from the original Japanese version: any form of violence, nudity, death, swearing and gay relationships or gay behaviour was taken out.

Even the main theme of love was not as highly present in the English as in the Japanese. The English theme song is a superhero song:

> I'm sorry I'm not straightforward,
>   I can say it in my dreams
>   My thoughts are about to short circuit,
>   I want to see you right now

versus...

> Fighting evil by moonlight,
>   Winning love by daylight,
>   Never running from a real fight,
>   She is the one named Sailor Moon

People actually die in the Japanese version. Something that surprised me even more since I was still used to it being a naive censored version.

You are not the first to ask this and there is a website dedicated to the differences called [smuncensored](http://www.smuncensored.com/season.php?season=1). It has an episode-by-episode color-coded review of all the differences. Looking at [episode 1](http://www.smuncensored.com/comparison.php?episodeid=1) I stopped counting at 50 differences in plot and story line. [Episode 2](http://www.smuncensored.com/comparison.php?episodeid=2) was skipped completely... and at [episode 46](http://www.smuncensored.com/comparison.php?episodeid=46) you can see that a total of 6 episodes got skipped.